# How control the flow of http streaming in node.js with piping

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, stream, pipe

As Node.js developer knows, node can pipe the stream flow to another resource like http response.

### Solution #1

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
   stream.pipe(res);
});
```

### Solution #2

There is another way to control flow of streaming and buffer response without piping

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);

    stream.on('data', function(data) {
        if (res.write(data) == false){ 
             stream.pause();
        }
    });

    stream.on('end', function(data) {
        res.end();
    });

    res.on('drain', function(data) {
        stream.resume();
    });


});
```

### Is solution #2 better than #1 ?

I think It's better because we can control the flow of stream to http response.
when response buffer is full and stream can't write data, stream will pause and when response become drain stream will resume

### My Problem

When I'm using the solution #2 my node application going to halt station and not response to other clients. this mean it only service to one client at a time !
I think this problem will occurs because node waiting to send `res.end()` to client and end the response. but I don't understand how to solve this issue.

If this solution is absolutely wrong and I just need to use `stream.pipe()` please show me how can I control the flow of piping with `resume` and `pause` functions

Answer (score 3):

Solution #1 is basically equivalent to #2, except it's shorter code and you don't have to worry about the backpressure details.

If your server is blocking other clients while writing the data, there's something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: This is my entire stream code, https://gist.github.com/ramin2nt2/6a53c88d8ffb64744751 can you show me where I gone wrong way ?

Comment: The code looks alright to me. Can you explain about the "not responding?" Is it that you can't make requests after 2 or 3 requests that are pending (if it's this, perhaps you're hitting the browser's per-site connection limit)? Or is it that you can't make new requests after making some number of requests and when no other requests are pending?

Comment: Actually, I think I may see why you are having issues now. Try changing `stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);` to `var stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);` and remove the `var stream = require('stream');`. Having that shared `stream` object is probably causing issues when the various events fire that use the current value of `stream` (causing actions to be performed on streams for other requests).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did your advice. this is the code https://gist.github.com/ramin2nt2/c5c22a4c4aee7b00345e . but still the node app response to one user at time and other request will pending.